# Randomize Color of an Object with Multiple Meshes

Tags: mesh, shaders, color, vertex-colors, random

I'm making a container with multiple meshes inside and I want to randomize the color when I duplicate it. Like the left red one in the picture I want to change its color between blue/red/green but instead of it all the meshes have randomized colors like on the right side. How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello @moonboots. I uploaded an example. In "Object" folder there is an object made from 3 cubes. and i duplicated the instances. so every object has different colors. 

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=XNzY9VBX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XNzY9VBX/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Cube*, *Cube.001* and *Cube.002* are 3 separate objects, not one object, so no wonder why they have different colors if you use the *Random* output, because *Random* will create one different color per object, if you want the whole object to have one unique color, join *Cube*, *Cube.001* and *Cube.002* into one object with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> and it will work as you want:

[image]

Comment: I've always tried to find a solution without joining them. Thanks for the help!